# check if a zip file has password-protection, in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zip

I have used ZipArchive library to zip and unzip files, but it doesn't give a clue about how to check if the zip file is password-protected. I need to be able to check whether a .zip file is password-protected. If it is, I will prompt the user for a password; otherwise just unzip it.

Anyone have an idea of how to check this? Is there an encryption bit on the file that I can test for? If so, how would I do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check zip local file header for a encryption flag. However, this will need some data parsing.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like something you want:

http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/API/classCZipFileHeader.aspx#0b3983cef7d3d4e2a7dff403e88b8883